# How can i list all tables involved in SQLAlchemy statements

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can i list all tables involved in SQLAlchemy statements ?
let assume we have the following query

```
query = session.query(Address).filter(Address.person == person)
```

how can list the tables that is used by this query 
in this case : Person , Address

Comment: Your query is (likely) not going to actually use the table underlying Person, but just compare `address.person_id = :person_id`. It'd help if you'd include your models in the question.

Comment: @Ilja Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

r-m-n answer is good , but it doesn't handle all cases , sub queries ,delete statements , exist statements etc

here is a general way to extract all tables

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.visitors import ClauseVisitor
from sqlalchemy import Table


def extract_tables(sql_stmt):
    tables = []
    visitor = ClauseVisitor()
    cluase_iter = visitor.iterate(elem)
    for e in cluase_iter:
        if isinstance(e, Table):
            tables.append(e)
        if isinstance(e, (ValuesBase, UpdateBase)):
            tables.append(e.table)
    return set(tables)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get all tables from [locate_all_froms](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.locate_all_froms), something like this

```
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.sql.selectable import Alias

tables = set()
for f in query.statement.locate_all_froms():
    if isinstance(f, Table):
        tables.add(f)
    elif isinstance(f, Alias):
        tables.add(f.element)
```

Comment: Thanks mate , How could i handle Insert and Delete with sub queries ?