# Sqlalchemy multiple engines and schema association

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Sqlalchemy  let you  handle two engines or more simultaneously.  It let you define different schemas and associate different  schema  to different  engines.

I would like to have a mixed mode.  Where  in case that we have a query that involved tables from two schemas they will  be associated with engine1 otherwise they will be associated with engine2 and engine3 corresponding to schema1 and schema2.

Is that possible?

Comment: I think you might be looking for [`binds`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.binds) mapping argument of Session, though not entirely sure.

Comment: @everila would this let me map mixed query to engine1 and non mixed query to appropriate engine?  Does it supports dynamic binding?

Comment: That complex system might require making a [routing Session](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/). I guess this is why you needed that ["get mappers/froms involved in a statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550683/how-can-i-list-all-tables-involved-in-sqlalchemy-statements) thing.

Comment: Relevant docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.get_bind

Comment: @Ilja,  Thanks mate, that looks interesting.  I will need to dig into this.  Thanks.